# Как восстановить Dump базы данных?

Tags: postgresql

Авторизовываюсь в БД, выполняю:

```
pg_restore -v "/path/to/file.sql"
```

И выводит это:

```
pg_restore: [archiver] input file appears to be a text format dump. Please use psql.
```

В дампе описано несколько БД.

В чем дело?

Comment: добавьте ключ -v и посмотрите, есть ли ошибки.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman ничего не выводит эта опция.

Comment: `pg_restore` - утилита вызываемая из командной строки

Comment: @norbornen я ее по-вашему откуда запускаю?

Comment: @Colibri по оформлению похоже, что из `psql`.

Comment: попробуйте запустить `perl -v` и `which perl`

Comment: @D-side http://pastebin.com/raw/KBALi5St

Comment: @MikhailVaysman `/usr/bin/perl`, например. Или `This is perl 5, version 18, subversion 2 (v5.18.2) built for darwin-thread-multi-2level`

Comment: @Colibri а, ну понятно. Нет, бэкапы через `psql` восстанавливаются несколько, э-э, иначе.

Comment: @D-side так я запустил это не из psql

Comment: @Colibri в этот раз да, а то, что описано в вопросе (до моей правки) -- откуда там `db_name` в промпте, если это не `psql`?

Comment: Убрать это одно, а как на счёт объяснить откуда оно там взялось с самого начала? :D

Comment: тогда `cat /path/to/file.sql | psql -U ... параметры коннекта`. комманду создания базы данных можно вручную удалить из дампа.

Answer (score 1):

Восстанавливать надо вот так

```
psql < "/path/to/file.sql"
```

Comment: В этом фале уже описаны `CREATE DATABASE` нескольких БД.

Comment: как вы создали `"/path/to/file.sql"`? какой командой?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman наверняка, pg_dump

Answer (score 1):

@Colibri, лови три моих скрипта (пользую под FreeBSD 9.0 пока), все рабочее, все работает :)

**db-backup.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh

export IP=192.168.1.47
export DB=database_clients

PGPASSWORD="password" /usr/local/bin/pg_dump -U pgsql -F t -f /root/temp/database_clients.tar database_clients
xz -9 /root/temp/database_clients.tar
```

**db-restore.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh

export IP=192.168.1.47
export DB=database_clients

dropdb -p 5432 -h $IP -U pgsql -W $DB
createdb -D pg_default -E UTF-8 -O pgsql -h $IP -U pgsql -W $DB
echo "GRANT CONNECT, TEMPORARY ON DATABASE $DB TO public;" > $DB.grant.sql
echo "GRANT ALL ON DATABASE $DB TO pgsql;" >> $DB.grant.sql
psql -h $IP -U pgsql -W -f $DB.grant.sql $DB
unxz database_clients.tar.xz
pg_restore -h $IP -p 5432 -U pgsql -v --role="pgsql" -d $DB ~/temp/database_clients.tar
```

**db-reindex.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh

export IP=192.168.1.47
export DB=database_clients

PGPASSWORD="password" /usr/local/bin/reindexdb -U pgsql -h $IP --all
```

При вызове скрипта на восстановление - нужно будет ввести несколько раз пароль. Моя недоработка, но уже все давно не восстанавливается, только бэкапится. Ну и лень. Надеюсь скрипты послужат шаблонами для ваших нужд.

ЗЫ: С путями там между скриптами небольшие "несоответствия" - мне так было надо.